# Joomla update results in a white screen and "Fatal Error: Class Not found"

Tags: logging, joomla, updates, fatal-error, restore

- I have Joomla 3.7, and did a backup of site via GoDaddy on the 10th, July 2018.
- I then updated Joomla to 3.8x.
- I got the white screen of death on both front end and back.
- Then I tried to Restore, and still white screen.
- I enabled turned on Php error reporting, and it said:

  > Fatal error: Class 'JLog' not found in /home/diversal/public_html/libraries/legacy/error/error.php on line 371

Unfortunately Godaddy has never ever trained their employees to use Joomla, only WordPress, so I'm not getting any help from them so far.

Comment: Regarding getting website/coding help from _any_ hosting company, it isn't really their job, regardless of whether you're using WordPress or Joomla. Their job is to keep the web servers running and secure. Sometimes hosts will offer some best-endeavours assistance, but they are not a free source of programming labour, and it's not their area of expertise anyway.

Comment: I would start with identifying whether the missing class `JLog` is part of a plugin or core Joomla. If it is a plugin, can you disable it temporarily until you have the core system working?

Comment: Thank you for getting back! How would I be able to disable it if I can't get into Joomla front/back end?

Comment: This is the full error I'm getting ' Fatal error: Class 'JLog' not found in /home/diversal/public_html/libraries/legacy/error/error.php on line 371'

Comment: Search your project space for a file containing `class JLog` or similar to see if you can load it manually (e.g. in an init file, Joomla must have something like that).

Comment: To disable a plugin in Joomla without the backend, [ask a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=joomla+disable+plugin+mysql&t=lm&ia=web). Lots of results there for you to try.

Comment: (Of course, if you are working on a live site and not a local copy, take a backup first).

Answer (score -1):

I asked my host to restore my site from their backups. It cost me $40 but all working now. I spent 4 days trying to sort out the white screen of death, following many solutions from searching. So well worth this small fee imo.

Front and back end of Joomla 3.9 were affected. Changing the PHP made no difference.

Now reluctant to update Joomla again as this caused the problem.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: @Andrew if you are a Joomla user, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and contribute to the specialized community which was created specifically to support Joomlers.